# One Hot Encoding for R

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, preprocessor, caret

Is there a nice R equivalent to sklearn.preprocessing's OneHotEncoder?

I want to fit an OHE on my train data, transform that, and then transform my test data by the same transformation.

For example, in python:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
train = pd.DataFrame(['a','a','b','c','d'])
test = pd.DataFrame(['a','a'])
ohe = OneHotEncoder(drop='first')
train_dummies = ohe.fit_transform(train)
test_dummies = ohe.transform(test)
```

The closest equivalent I can find in R is caret's dummyVars(), but the following snippet fails:

```
library(caret)
train = data.frame(a=c('a','a','b','c','d'))
dummies = dummyVars(~ ., data = train)
train_dummies = predict(dummies, newdata = train)
test = data.frame(a=c('a','a'))
test_dummies = predict(dummies, newdata = test)
```

With

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

This failure occurs because *a* in test only has one level, despite dummies being fitted on *a* in train with 4 levels. Is there a better equivalent in R, or if necessary some fudge to make this one work? Also is there any way to replicate 'droppping the first level' as per python?

Comment: I do not know what you are doing but `data.frame(model.matrix(~a+0, train))` will give you one hot encoding

Comment: Or even `b <- factor(train$a)` then do `diag(nlevels(b))[b, ]`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to transfer the variable to factors before using `dummyVars`

```
# Create train and test data frames
train <- data.frame(a = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
test <- data.frame(a = c('a', 'a'))

# Convert input variables to factors
train$a <- as.factor(train$a)
test$a <- as.factor(test$a)

# Perform one-hot encoding using caret
dummies <- caret::dummyVars("~.", data = train)
train_dummies <- predict(dummies, newdata = train)
test_dummies <- predict(dummies, newdata = test)
```

```
> dummies
Dummy Variable Object

Formula: ~.
<environment: 0x7f9dd8053160>
1 variables, 1 factors
Variables and levels will be separated by '.'
A less than full rank encoding is used

> test_dummies
  a.a a.b a.c a.d
1   1   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

In a `tidymodels` approach, you could make one-hot encoding part of your data processing `recipe`. Calling `prep()` performs the encoding with the indicated data (`df_training` in my example), and you can see how its applied when you use this pre-processing recipe to `bake` the testing set.

```r
library(tidymodels)

df <- data.frame(a=c('a','a','a','a','b','c','d',
                     'b','b','a','c','c','d'))

set.seed(123)

df_split <- initial_split(df)

df_testing <- testing(df_split)
df_training <- training(df_split)

df_testing
#>    a
#> 7  d
#> 8  b
#> 9  b
#> 11 c
df_training
#>    a
#> 3  a
#> 13 d
#> 10 a
#> 2  a
#> 6  c
#> 12 c
#> 5  b
#> 4  a
#> 1  a

df_ohe <-
  recipe(~., data = df_training) %>%
  step_dummy(a, one_hot = TRUE)

df_ohe %>%
  prep() %>%
  bake(new_data = NULL)
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>     a_a   a_b   a_c   a_d
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     0     0     0
#> 2     0     0     0     1
#> 3     1     0     0     0
#> 4     1     0     0     0
#> 5     0     0     1     0
#> 6     0     0     1     0
#> 7     0     1     0     0
#> 8     1     0     0     0
#> 9     1     0     0     0

df_ohe %>%
  prep() %>%
  bake(new_data = df_testing)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>     a_a   a_b   a_c   a_d
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0     0     0     1
#> 2     0     1     0     0
#> 3     0     1     0     0
#> 4     0     0     1     0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There's `fastDummies` in R for one-hot encoding.

```r
library(fastDummies)

train = data.frame(col=c('a','a','b','c','d'))
dummy_cols(train, 
          remove_first_dummy = T,
          remove_selected_columns = T)
```

**Output**

```
  col_b col_c col_d
1     0     0     0
2     0     0     0
3     1     0     0
4     0     1     0
5     0     0     1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm looking for a OHE mechanism that stores the transformation, so that it can be applied subsequently to a test data set. I could manually convert all character columns in train and test into factor, store the levels from those columns in train, and apply those factor levels to test - but that sounds very painful! Surely there's a better way?